# cant make 'cucumberOpts' work on webdriverIO runner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, webdriver-io

I'm using a framework called: "cucumber-boilerplate" you can find it in 
github: [cucumber-boilerplate](https://github.com/webdriverio/cucumber-boilerplate)

if you follow the link, in the 'test' folder there is a conf.js file, mine looks like this:

```js
exports.config = {

    /**
     * language of your feature files
     * options: french, spanish, norwegian, polish, german, russian
     */
    language: 'english',

    /**
     * set selenium host and port
     */
    selenium: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 5555
    },

    /**
     * webdriverio options
     *
     * - logLevel: stdout log level
     *   Options: *verbose* | *silent* | *command* | *data* | *result*
     *
     * - coloredLogs: Enables colors for log output
     *   default: true
     *
     * - singleton: Set to true if you always want to reuse the same remote
     *   default: false
     *
     * - waitforTimeout: Default timeout for all waitForXXX commands
     *   default: 500
     */
    options: {
        logLevel: 'verbose',
  cucumberOpts: {
   failFast:true,
   require: [],        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
   backtrace: false,   // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
   compiler: [],       // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
   dryRun: false,      // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
   failFast: false,    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
   format: ['json:../result.json','pretty','html'], // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
   colors: false,       // <boolean> disable colors in formatter output
   snippets: true,     // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
   source: true,       // <boolean> hide source uris
   profile: [],        // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
   require: [],        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
   strict: true,      // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
   tags: [],           // <string[]> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
   timeout: 20000,      // <number> timeout for step definitions
   ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
  }
 
    },

    /**
     * desired capabilities
     */
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    },
 
 
 
 reporters: ['dot', 'allure'],
 
    /**
     * location of feature files
     */
    featureFiles: [
       'test/features/automation/Registration/Registration.feature'
 ],
    /**
     * environment variables
     *
     * - baseUrl: sets base url for `Given I open the site "/some/url.html"`
     */
    env: {
        baseUrl: '<my site URL>'
    },

    /**
     * mocha options
     * @see http://mochajs.org/
     */
    mochaOpts: {
        reporter: 'spec',
        timeout: 25000,
        require: 'chai'
    }
};
```

my run.js file runs and activate the correct feature but none of the 'cucumberOpts' takes effect, especially the report format and colors.

your help is very much appriciated:)

Comment: Please see answer on github https://github.com/webdriverio/cucumber-boilerplate/issues/51#issuecomment-232276364